# Running a basic simulation with cake probabilities. How do I code?

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, probability

I want to run a basic simulation to check observed observation against theoretical.

There are five cakes with the following probabilities of being chosen

```
Chocolate: 40%
Vanilla: 40%
Caramel: 10%
Banana: 5%
Coffee: 5%
```

Now if there was an equal probability I realise that I could use the sample function

i.e.

```
cake <- c('choc', 'van', 'car', 'ban', 'cof')
sample(x = cake, size = 1)
```

How would I factor in the probabilities I listed above?

Comment: check out the `prob` argument in `?sample`.

Comment: Could you offer a more detailed example using my data?

Answer (score 0):

```
cake <- c('choc', 'van', 'car', 'ban', 'cof')
cprobs<- c(.4,.4,.1,.05,.05)
sample(x = cake, size = 1,prob =cprobs)
```

prob argument is a vector that contains probabilities of x.

Comment: Please add explaination.

Comment: @DanielCheung ok i'm adding